# Ruby variable not working properly in function

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I have this function:

```
def find_deleted_number(arr, mixed_arr)

    default = 0

    arr.each do |i|
        if mixed_arr.include?(arr[i]) == true
            default += arr[i]
        else 
            return arr[i]
        end
    end
    return default  
end

find_deleted_number([1,2,3,4,5], [3,4,1,5])
#=> 2 (as expected)

find_deleted_number([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1,9,7,4,6,2,3,8])
#=> 5 (as expected)

find_deleted_number([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [5,7,6,9,4,8,1,2,3])
#=> nil (expected 45)
```

The idea is for the function to check which number is in arr but not in mixed_arr. That's all good but the problem is that when both arrays are the same, I want it to give me the sum of every value in one of the arrays (that's why I do `default += arr[i]`). But the result is `nil` and I dont quite understand why. If possible I would like to understand the reason why it is failing.

Comment: You can simplify your loop by using [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#sum-method)

Comment: What do you expect from this case: `find_deleted_number([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9], [5,7,6,9,4,8,1,2,3])`? Note the repeated `9`. Of course if this case was a possible input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr.each` iterates over elements of `arr`, not over indexes. Therefore, you need to change `arr[i]` to `i`.

The full answer is:

```
def find_deleted_number(arr, mixed_arr)
  default = 0

  arr.each do |i|
    if mixed_arr.include?(i)
      default += i
    else 
      return i
    end
  end

  default  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is failing as @yzalavin said.

You could also simplify your code:

```rb
def find_deleted_number(arr, mixed_arr)
  return arr.sum if arr.sort == mixed_arr.sort

  (arr - mixed_arr).first
end
```

And @Stefan provide an even shorter one-liner:

```rb
(arr - mixed_arr).first || arr.sum
```

Comment: Even shorter: `(arr - mixed_arr).first || arr.sum`

Comment: @Stefan Wow impressive : )

Comment: Suppose `arr = [1,2]; mixed = [1,2,3]`. Then `arr.sort == mixed_arr.sort #=> false`, so `(arr - mixed_arr).first #=> [].first #=> nil` is returned, which is incorrect.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, this just works within  condition: `The idea is for the function to check which number is in arr but not in mixed_arr.`